# Array contains duplicate, implementation not working with the forEach syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a function if an array of integers has duplicate values, so I came up with the following implementation, and it works:

```js
const containsDuplicate = (nums) => {
    const hashTable = {}
    
    for (let num in nums) {
        const numValue = nums[num]
        if (numValue in hashTable) return true
        hashTable[numValue] = "a"
    }
    
    return false
};
```

But, I want to know a semantic way to implement this following ES6 style, I tried the `.forEach` but, I discovered that I cant break out of it.

Comment: `return true` inside the `forEach` call returns the callback function you passed to it, not the outside function.

Comment: "*way more elegant and looks like the most semantic implementation in ES6*" - then you're looking for `for (const num of nums)`, not `.forEach()`

Comment: I edited my question, would you consider submiting an answer to that?